# Unable to forward port 6000

Tags: windows-10

I am trying to run the following command in Windows 10:

```
adb forward tcp:6000 localfilesystem:/data/local/debugger-socket
```

I am getting an error and it's not working:

```
adb.exe: error: cannot bind listener: cannot bind to 127.0.0.1:6000: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. (10013)
```

I am running the cmd window as admin. How can I allow this?

I don't have an anti-virus, and windows firewall is disabled.

Comment: Have you made sure nothing else is on port 6000?

Comment: The issue was solved but I don't know how I managed it.